# Custom permalink structure for custom post types including multiple taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, taxonomy, rewrite-rules

The goal is to have a structure like this: **example.com/tax_1/tax_2/post_name**

This code produces the right structure but the post can't be found (404)

```
// Register custom post types
function register_work() {
    $args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'label' => 'Projekt',
        'menu_name' => 'work',
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-view-site',
        'has_archive' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'thumbnail', 'title' ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => '%filter_1%/%filter_2%',
            'with_front' => false
        )
        );
    register_post_type( 'work', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_work' );

// Register tax
function work_tax() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'filter',
        'work',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Tags' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'filter',
                'with_front' => false
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'work_tax' );

// Replace permalink slug
function custom_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'work' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'filter' );
        if( $terms ){
            $find = array('%filter_1%','%filter_2%');
            $replace = array($terms[0]->slug,$terms[1]->slug);
            return str_replace($find, $replace, $post_link);
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```

I have regenerated the .htaccess file by saving the permalinks in the settings menu.

Does anyone know if it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This code produces the right structure but the post can't be found
> (404)

That is because the custom *rewrite tags* (`%filter_1%` and `%filter_2%`) appeared as-is in the generated rewrite rules (in the database). So you need to register the tags so that they're replaced with the proper RegEx (regular expression) pattern when WordPress (re-)generates the rules.

And you can register them using [`add_rewrite_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/) like so:

```php
function register_work() {
    // Register the custom rewrite tags.
    add_rewrite_tag( '%filter_1%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%filter_2%', '([^/]+)' );

    // ... then register the post type.
}
```

And that should fix the error, but you should know that your post type's rewrite rules will result in issues like Pages (posts of the `page` type) showing the homepage instead of the correct Page.

So you should just use a unique rewrite base, e.g. `work` as in `'slug' => 'work/%filter_1%/%filter_2%'` to avoid clashes with other rewrite rules, particularly the default ones in WordPress.

However, if you really must use no rewrite base there, then there is a way.

- But each time after you created or deleted a `filter` term, or maybe changed its *slug*, you need to manually flush the rewrite rules by simply visiting the permalink settings page.

  **Note:** Yes there is a programmatic way to automatically flush the rewrite rules, but doing it manually is really easy, so just create/edit/delete your `filter` terms *in bulk* and then manually flush the rewrite rules. :)
- And there should be no posts (Pages, Posts, CPTs) or terms having the same slug as used by your `filter` terms. I.e. If you have a `filter` term with the slug `foo`, then you should have **no** posts or terms (in other taxonomies) having the slug `foo`.

  But what I really mean is, you can use the same slug, but not in all cases and be wary. For example, if a `work` CPT post has `foo/bar/baz` as the permalink, then there should be no Page with that *path*, i.e. a Page with the slug `baz` that's a child of the `bar` and `foo` Pages.

So if those are good to you, then here's the code you can try:

```php
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function ( $rules ) {
    $terms = get_terms( [
        'taxonomy'   => 'filter',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'fields'     => 'slugs',
    ] );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $slug ) {
            $match = "^{$slug}/(.*?)/([^/]+)(?:/(\d+)|)/?$";
            $query = 'index.php?post_type=work&work=$matches[2]&name=$matches[2]&page=$matches[3]';
            $rules[ $match ] = $query;
        }
    }

    return $rules;
} );
```

**And** in addition to that code:

- In `register_work()`, use `work` as the base: `'slug' => 'work/%filter_1%/%filter_2%',`
- Then in the `custom_permalinks()` function:

  ```php
  // You need to replace this:
  $find = array('%filter_1%','%filter_2%');

  // with this:
  $find = array('work/%filter_1%','%filter_2%');
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for a great and detailed answer!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, and I added extra notes there. :)